# Meaning of "whoa"

Tags: meaning, history

Some dictionaries define *whoa* as *Stop!* while some define it as *an expression of surprise/astonishment*. Is there such a word as *whoa*, where did it originate from and what is its actual meaning?

Comment: Voting to close as general reference. If the word appears in dictionaries, yes, such a word exists. Many words have multiple meanings.

Comment: But where does it original? (The history of Whoa).

Comment: Questions about words' origins can often be found at the end of a dictionary entry or in an etymology dictionary, both of which are easily accessible online. Here's a link that should help you: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=whoa&searchmode=none

Comment: @onomatomaniak +1 Thanks for that link. I find it pretty useful. I am going to bookmark it.

Comment: see my answer below for definitions and etymology

Comment: IMHO, *whoa* and *woah* are different.  I may be wrong, but it's not general reference.

Comment: @TimLymington, never thought that there is also such a English term `woah`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meanings of *whoa*:

1. To express surprise (interj)
2. To express astonishment(interj)
3. To indicate a desire for one to end that of which they are speaking (interj)
4. Evolved from a song to describe something that you're not quite sure exactly how to describe (adj)

*Whoa* can also be spelled *woah* though there are many arguments started by bored people about which way is correct.

1. "Whoa! Don't do that, you scared me."
2. "Whoa, that roller coaster is fast."
3. "Whoa, okay, that's enough."
4. "That car is so cool, it's like, whoa."

Comment: +1 for 'arguments started by bored people'.  As one of such, I would say that *woah* expressing surprise is different from *whoa* meaning 'slow down or stop', but I'm not bigoted about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is very obviously an English word. It comes ultimately from Old French *ho*, but I agree that this is a question that hardly needs to be asked here.

Comment: Hi Barrie, can you tell me where you get the information that the word actually came from Old French oh?

Comment: @Larry Morries: The Oxford English Dictionary <http://www.oed.com/>, but it's available only through paid subscription.

Answer (score 2):

I had thought *Whoa* is the sound a cowboy let out to signal his horse to slow down (and stop). Whence, whoa means 'slow down (to stop)'.

> [**whoa**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whoa)
>   [hwoh, woh]
>   *interjection*
>   stop! (used especially to horses).
>
> Origin:
>   1615–25;  dialectal variant of ho

1623, a cry to call attention from a distance, a variant of who. As a command to stop a horse, it is attested from 1843, a variant of ho. As an expression of delight or surprise (1980s) it has gradually superseded wow, which was very popular 1960s.  [Etymonline]